# SVN User authentication using Command Line or Python

Tags: python, svn, tortoisesvn, pysvn

I need to verify if some user is valid SVN user or not in my application. I want to achieve this using SVN commandline tools/Tortoise SVN Commndline or Python in windows. I looked up PySVN but it seems to me that there is no way to authenticate a current user in that library.
Please suggest some way of doing the same.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for `pysvn.Client.callback_*` and you will see that the methods you have to provide handle prompting for passwords and errors if they don't match.

Comment: Yes but that callback only gets called if there is no username password in cache. I couldn't find any method in which I can supply username password information and get the results. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pysvn to authenticate using the [callback_get_login](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_callback_get_login).

According to the [documentation](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html):

> callback_get_login is called each time subversion needs a username and
>   password in the realm to access a repository and has no cached
>   credentials.

Comment: Please see my comment to Steve Barnes's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite hard to make it work. I came up with following result:

```
def get_prepared_svn_client(self, username, pwd):
    client=pysvn.Client()
    class OneAttemptLogin:
        """ 
        if login failed, pysvn goes into infinite loop.
        this class is used as callback; it allows only one login attempt
        """
        def __init__(self, username, pwd):
            self.attempt_tried=False
            self.username=username
            self.pwd=pwd
        def __call__(self, x,y,z):
            if not self.attempt_tried:
                self.attempt_tried=True
                return (True, self.username, self.pwd, False)
            else:
                return (False, "xx", "xx", False)
    client.callback_get_login=OneAttemptLogin(username, pwd)
    client.set_auth_cache(False)
    client.set_store_passwords(False)
    client.set_default_username('')
    client.set_default_password('')
    client.set_interactive(False)
    return client
```

What it does:

1. it uses one-attempt callback. Because pysvn will try the same
   credentials over and over if they won't work, we need to stop it.
2. No credentials will be preserved (you can omit it if it's not
   desired behaviour)
3. Clear default username and password, so cache will not be used
4. disable prompt